# Set a response page with instance and parameter

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5

I'm stuck with a redirection in Wicket (1.5) and the different versiont of the `setResponsePage`. 
I mount a page with parameters, but I cant use the version with the class sinc I want to use a specific constructor to create this page in order to pass some arguments. When I do that, the generated url does not display the parameters.

Here is the code :

```
// WicketApplication
mount(new MountedMapper("create/${param}/full", MyPage.class));
// In a page
PageParameters parameters = new PageParameters();
parameters.add("param", "value");
// URL OK : create/value/full
setResponsePage(MyPage.class, parameters);
// URL KO : create//full
setResponsePage(new MyPage(parameters, arguments...));
```

Is there any way to set a custom response page with parameters and an instance of a page ? A way to do something like `setResponsePage(new MyPage(parameters, arguments...), parameters);`

Comment: What are you passing as your arguments?  You shouldn't be passing any arguments to your page other than the page parameters, but how to work around your issue will depend on what you're trying to pass.

Comment: The idea is to pass the Model of the page, so it can be initialized with the data. If you can not pass it as argument, how can you do it ?

Comment: You can pass a model to your [page's constructor](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/WebPage.html#WebPage%28org.apache.wicket.model.IModel%29).  In that case you just wouldn't include the page parameters in the constructor.

Comment: So it's either one or the other ? Is there a better choice than using the session to pass the model ? Or is there a way to not use the url generated by the MountedMapper when I generate the page instance ? I need the model, but the `//` in the generated url is not acceptable (make another app crash badly...)

Answer (score 0):

Make these two changes:

1. Use overloaded constructors, one taking only [PageParameters](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/WebPage.html#WebPage%28org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.parameter.PageParameters%29) for when you need to pass parameters, and the other taking only an [IModel](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/WebPage.html#WebPage%28org.apache.wicket.model.IModel%29) for when you need to pass a model.
2. Change the `$` to a `#` to make your param place holder optional and solve your URL issue:

   ```
   mount(new MountedMapper("create/#{param}/full", MyPage.class));
   ```